# Java servlet Tomcat random stackoverflowerror

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, servlets, stack-overflow

I have a very strange issue here.

When I do a specific action in my webapp, I get random `StackOverFlowError`.  See the log file below.

I'm working with `Win10 64bit`, `Tomcat 8.5.12 64bit` and `Java 1.8.0.121`.

I have already got a `StackOverFlowError` on:

- javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getCookies()
- javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getCharacterEncoding()
- org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute()
- org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute()
- javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted()
- org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession()
- ...

**I have this issue only if I deploy my webapp on a specific context path (ex:http://localhost:8080/mywebapp), if I deploy on the root (http://localhost:8080/), I don't have this issue.**

**I get this issue with older versions of my app, older versions worked well before, so the solution isn't in the app code I think.**

I have already tested:

- with an older or with the last Tomcat version
- with Tomcat 32 or 64 bit version
- with a older or last Java version
- with Java 32 or 64 bit
- with serveral web browser
- with an older version of my app (It worked well before)
- on an other PC

Nothing works...

It's caused by a forward request issue I think.
Can someone help me to solve this issue?

TIA,

```
27-Mar-2017 14:38:45.374 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet AliasServlet threw exception
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:246)
    (...)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:359)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    (...)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)

27-Mar-2017 14:38:45.379 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet AliasServlet threw exception
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    (...)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.unwrapRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:789)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    (...)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.dynPage(AliasServlet.java:254)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.processRequest(AliasServlet.java:55)
    at be.mims.ali.web.servlet.AliasServlet.doPost(AliasServlet.java:436)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: In your `AliasServlet`, do you call `ServletRequestWrapper.setRequest(ServletRequest request)` to make the wrapper point to itself? Because that seems to be the issue.

Comment: @Andreas No explicit `setRequest()`, I do `HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);`